# variable is empty even after using global to make it global scoped

Tags: python, discord.py, global

I want my program to welcome someone as soon as they join a discord server (discord.py), and that part works fine. However, to get the guild name, my program sends a message in a channel, and then it checks if it sent the message in the required channel and gets the guild name from there using `message.guild.name`. now for this to work, it needs to be global scoped because i have two functions in my code, one being `on_message` and the other being `on_member_join`. Somehow, it works without an error but when it's sending the welcome message, it just registers the guild name as an empty string. Why?

Here's my code for more clarity:

```
client = discord.Client()
serverName = ""

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "a new member has arrived" and message.author == client.user:
        global serverName
        serverName = message.guild.name

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Welcome to " + serverName) #here it shows the initially declared empty string.
    await member.send(embed=embed)
    await client.get_channel(channelId).send("A new member has arrived")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to send a message to get the guild name.
On member join there is a `discord.Member` parameter which is a member of the guild. there u can get the guild name by `member.guild.name`